# Einstein Data Analysis Scope

Tags: einstein

I was wondering if Einstein will only analyse and provide predictive insights and recommendations based on the actual org I am using, or will it take it one step further and provide the same based on data collected across multiple orgs (if it does).

For example:

> Predictive Lead Scoring.
>
> - Automatically prioritize the highest value leads based on their    likelihood to convert with defined lead scores.
> - Help reps determine which leads to focus on first to convert leads    faster.
> - Identify the top factors that determine predictive lead scores to    uncover what’s driving the best leads.
> - Track key lead score metrics across your org including average lead    scores, conversion rates, and lead score distribution to measure the
>     health of incoming leads.

Multiple factors/variables are used to calculate and prioritize lead conversions. If similar variables/factors are shared amongst other orgs (from other salesforce customers), will Einstein use this to help predict my lead conversions or restrict the data analysed for this to my org?

Since Einstein has a vast number of features across multiple products,

- Sales Cloud Einstein
- Marketing Cloud Einstein
- Community Cloud Einstein
- Analytics Cloud Einstein
- Commerce Cloud Einstein

If multiple org data analysis is supported by Einstein, how Will we know what features take advantage of this?